# Magento If else statement in transactional emails - surely this is simple?

Tags: magento

Please can someone help answer this (what I thought would be a very simple exercise, but after spending ages checking this forum for similar answers unfortunately I am still no clearer).

Basically we have our invoice transactional email that has this code:

```
<td class="method-info">
<h6>Payment method:</h6>
<p>Payment has been received</p>
</td>
```

Basically under Payment method it just used to say the default {{var payment_html}} so this was replaced with 'Payment has been received'

However for the payment after delivery method ('cashondelivery') it should not say 'Payment has been received' as the customer hasn't paid yet!

So basically could someone please replace my basic style logic below to work in the email

```
<td class="method-info">
<h6>Payment method:</h6>                   

if {{var payment_html}} is 'Payment after delivery'
  echo  {{var payment_html}} 
else
   echo 'Payment has been received' 
endif
</td>
```

Sorry to ask such as basic question, but we are looking for a new freelance magento developer!

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

In email template, we cannot use logical expression in `{{if}}` or `{{depend}}` condition like,

```
{{if order.getPayment().getMethod()=="cashondelivery"}}
Payment after delivery
{{else}}
{{var payment_html}}
{{/if}}
```

So to render 'Payment after delivery' text if payment method is cashondelivery for invoice template, you have to override `sendEmail` function of `Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Invoice` class.

In that function, you can add a condition like,

```
if($order->getPayment()->getMethod()=='cashondelivery'){
    $paymentBlockHtml = Mage::helper('sales')->__('Payment after delivery');
}
```

[image: code_snippet_screenshot]

Hope it helps!